# IOS Swift confusing error on using nib file for reusable Views

Tags: ios, uiview, swift3, nib

I am trying to do a simple reusable view and for some reason I am getting a un-specific error . I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-55qZYc9qI . As stated this is my first time trying this . Everything compiles correctly but when I go to that View I get a runtime error . What is weird is that I followed that tutorial exactly and am getting the error. The names are correct and the view is connected properly . Any suggestions

```
import UIKit

class streamShared: UIView {
    @IBOutlet var view: streamShared!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        UINib(nibName: "streamShared", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)
      addSubview(view)
}
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got yourself an infinite recursion: `streamShared.init(coder:)` is calling itself.

I think the subview should be of type `UIView`:

```
import UIKit

// PLEASE name your classes, structs and enums Capitalized!
class StreamShared: UIView {

    var view: UIView!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.view = UINib(nibName: "streamShared", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(view)
    }
}
```

Also, change the class of the main view in your xib file to the default `UIView` (grayed); otherwise, when reading the xib and instantiating the views contained therein, `StreamShared.init(coder:)` will still be called.